# Изменение цвета ячейки относительно позиции персонажа

Tags: javascript, if, project

Всем привет! Друзья, не могли бы подсказать, как правильно реализовать изменение цвета ячейки относительно позиции выбранного персонажа?

1. У меня есть выделенный персонаж (желтый кружок)
2. У него есть максимальная дистанции атаки и движения (Допустим "swordsman" (1 клетка - дистанция атаки, 4 клетки - дистаниция передвижения)
3. Я хочу сделать так чтобы
   а) относительно максимальной дистанцию движения персонажа, все клетки вокруг при наведение на них выделялись зелёным
   б) если в допустимой зоне атаки, вражеский персонаж становился выделен красным при наведение на него

Буду очень благодарен если вы поможете!
Ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/Logot1n/js-advanced-diploma
Код прописывается в модуле GameController, основные события прописаны, хотел бы дополнить условиями выше. Не совсем понимаю, как это проделать :(